# How to speed up a query containing HAVING?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, having

I have a table with close to a billion records, and need to query it with `HAVING`. It's very slow (about 15 minutes on decent hardware). How to speed it up?

```
SELECT ((mean - 3.0E-4)/(stddev/sqrt(N))) as t, ttest.strategyid, mean, stddev, N, 
  kurtosis, strategies.strategyId 
FROM ttest,strategies 
WHERE ttest.strategyid=strategies.id AND dataset=3 AND patternclassid="1" 
  AND exitclassid="1" AND N>= 300 HAVING t>=1.8
```

I think the problem is `t` cannot be indexed because it needs to be computed. I cannot add it as a column because the '3.0E-4' will vary per query.

Table:

```
create table ttest (
  strategyid bigint,
  patternclassid integer not null,
  exitclassid integer not null,
  dataset integer not null,
  N integer,
  mean double,
  stddev double,
  skewness double,
  kurtosis double,

  primary key (strategyid, dataset)
);
create index ti3 on ttest (mean);
create index ti4 on ttest (dataset,patternclassid,exitclassid,N);

create table strategies (
  id bigint ,
  strategyId varchar(500),

  primary key(id),
  unique key(strategyId)
);
```

`explain select..` :

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | ttest | NULL | range | PRIMARY,ti4 | ti4 | 17 | NULL | 1910344 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
| 1 | SIMPLE | strategies | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | Jellyfish_test.ttest.strategyid | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |

Comment: Do everything involving ttest in a subquery (or cte) and then join strategies

Comment: if you don't mind, I need a bit more help. I though this would do the trick: ```select ((mean-3.0E-4)/stddev/sqrt(N)),  ttest.strategyid, mean, stddev, N, skewness, kurtosis, strategies.strategyId FROM ttest,strategies where ttest.strategyid=strategies.id AND dataset=3 AND patternclassid="1" AND exitclassid="1" AND N>= 300 and (select ((mean - 3.0E-4)/(stddev/sqrt(N))) from ttest)
>1.8 ;``` Unfortunately:
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Why is `strategyid in both tables, yet not what you are JOINing on?

Comment: The error you encountered was due to the unnecessary `SELECT`.  The expression can simply be used in the `WHERE` clause,  (See my answer.)

Comment: CTE is a new-fangled frill that does not provide any benefit in _this_ case.

Comment: BUG?  Shouldn't it be `ABS(t) >= 1.8`?  (This won't change any optimizations in the Answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I've never seen `HAVING` being used like this; for 20+ years I've assumed it can only be used in `GROUP BY` situations!

Anyway, IMHO you don't need it here, as Rick James points out, you can put it all in the `WHERE`.
Rewriting it a bit I end up with:

```
SELECT ((t.mean - 3.0E-4)/(t.stddev/sqrt(t.N))) as t, 
       t.strategyid, 
       t.mean, 
       t.stddev, 
       t.N, 
       t.kurtosis, 
       s.strategyId 
 FROM ttest t,
 JOIN strategies s
   ON s.id = t.strategyid =  
WHERE t.dataset=3 
  AND t.patternclassid="1" 
  AND t.exitclassid="1" 
  AND t.N>= 300 
  AND ((t.mean - 3.0E-4)/(t.stddev/sqrt(t.N))) >= 1.8
```

Most of that we can indeed foresee a reasonable index. The problem remains with  the last calculation:

```
  AND ((t.mean - 3.0E-4)/(t.stddev/sqrt(t.N))) >= 1.8
```

However, before we go to that: how many rows are there if you ignore this 'formula'? 100? 200? If so, indexing as foreseen in Rick James' answer should be sufficient IMHO.
If it's 1000's or many more than the question becomes: how much of those are thrown out by the formula? 1%? 50% 99%? If it's on the low side then again, indexing as proposed by Rick James will do. If however you only need to keep a few you may want to further optimize this and index accordingly.
From your explanation I understand that `3.0E-4` is variable so we can't include it in the index.. so we'll need to extract the parts we can:

If my algebra isn't failing me you can play with the formula like this:

```
 AND ((t.mean - 3.0E-4) / (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N))) >= 1.8
 AND ((t.mean - 3.0E-4) ) >=  1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N))
 AND   t.mean - 3.0E-4    >= (1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N)))
 AND          - 3.0E-4    >= (1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N))) - t.mean
```

So the query becomes:

```
SELECT ((t.mean - 3.0E-4)/(t.stddev/sqrt(t.N))) as t, 
       t.strategyid, 
       t.mean, 
       t.stddev, 
       t.N, 
       t.kurtosis, 
       s.strategyId 
 FROM ttest t,
 JOIN strategies s
   ON s.id = t.strategyid =  
WHERE t.dataset=3 
  AND t.patternclassid="1" 
  AND t.exitclassid="1" 
  AND t.N>= 300 
  AND (1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N))) - t.mean <= -3.0E-4
```

I'm not familiar with mysql but glancing the documentation it should be possible to include 'generated columns' in the index. So, we'll do exactly that with `(1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N)) - t.mean)`.

Your indexed fields thus become:

`dataset, paternclassid, exitclassid, N, (1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N))) - t.mean)`

Note that the system will have to calculate this value for each and every row on insert (and possibly update) you do on the table. However, once there (and indexed) it should make the query quite a bit faster.

Comment: At the moment I can't think of anything why I needed the HAVING. Now it just seems stupid. I like your formula manipulation. Unfortunately, the 1.8 can vary as well... But since there are only a few usefull variations I thought I'd give it a try. After creating an index specifically for "1.8", the query was finished in 10 seconds. Great job! (To answer your question: the number of results are anywhere from a few hundred to ten-thousand)

Comment: Making an expression [_sargable_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) is a valid optimization.  The algebraic reformulations you mention do not achieve that, so they won't help any.  (Or at least not by a noticeable amount.)

Comment: @RickJames Assuming we make `(1.8 * (t.stddev / sqrt(t.N))) - t.mean)` a calculated column (or 'generated' in mysql-speak?) and index that one, how is that not sargable then? What else would be needed? (I like the wikipedia page btw)

Comment: @deroby - In _this_ case, a generated, indexed, column may not help.  There is already one "range" test (`N>=300`).  The optimizer cannot use 2 range tests in an INDEX.

Comment: @RickJames That would make sense, but on the other hand it makes the index 'covering' and thus avoid lots of bookmark lookups. Maybe simply `INCLUDE`ing the field (or even the formula?) might be sufficient. Again, I have no experience with MySQL so not entirely sure if that's applicable here. Going by @markiemark 's test results, having the calculated field in there did bring the runtime down vs not having it in there so something must be at play... SQL can be weird at times =)

Comment: @deroby - Yes "covering" is beneficial. Sometimes it helps a lot, sometimes only a little; it is hard to predict how much.

Answer (score 1):

The query needs to reformulated *and* an index needs to be added.

Plan A:

```
SELECT  ((tt.mean - 3.0E-4)/(tt.stddev/sqrt(tt.N))) as t,
        tt.strategyid, tt.mean, tt.stddev, tt.N, tt.kurtosis,
        s.strategyId
    FROM  ttest AS tt
    JOIN  strategies AS s  ON tt.strategyid = s.id
    WHERE  tt.dataset = 3
      AND  tt.patternclassid = 1
      AND  tt.exitclassid = 1
      AND  tt.N >= 300
      AND  ((tt.mean - 3.0E-4)/(tt.stddev/sqrt(tt.N))) >= 1.8
```

and a 'composite' and 'covering' index on test.  Replace your `ti4` with this (to make it 'covering'):

```
INDEX(dataset, patternclassid, exitclassid,  -- any order
      N, strategyid)     -- in this order
```

Plan B:

```
SELECT  ((tt.mean - 3.0E-4)/(tt.stddev/sqrt(tt.N))) as t,
        tt.strategyid, tt.mean, tt.stddev, tt.N, tt.kurtosis,
        ( SELECT s.strategyId 
              FROM strategies AS s
              WHERE s.id = tt.strategyid = s.id
        ) AS strategyId
    FROM  ttest AS tt
    WHERE  tt.dataset = 3
      AND  tt.patternclassid = 1
      AND  tt.exitclassid = 1
      AND  tt.N >= 300
      AND  ((tt.mean - 3.0E-4)/(tt.stddev/sqrt(tt.N))) >= 1.8
```

With the same index.

Unfortunately the expression for `t` needs to be repeated.  By moving it from `HAVING` to `WHERE`, avoids gathering unwanted rows, only to end up throwing them away.  *Maybe* the optimizer will do that automatically.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see.

Also, it is unclear whether one of the two formulations will run faster than the other.

Comment: Plan A takes 27 seconds (21 after a couple of tries), plan B 29 seconds (23 after a couple of tries). A huge difference to the 15 minutes before!

Comment: @Markiemark - Thanks for the timings.  (I assume it was _with_ the new index?)

Comment: Yes, with the new index.